# Powershell scrip forloop gettings errors

Tags: powershell, for-loop

Trying to automate a task using PowerShell. The command that I am using is `New-NpsRadiusClient`. I have a CSV file with four columns:

- Name
- IPAddress
- SharedSecret
- Vendor

I'm new to PowerShell. I have no experience at all. How do I get this to work? Thanks.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\npsDevices.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    New-NpsRadiusClient -Name $ClientName -Address $IPAddress -VendorName $Vendor -SharedSecret $strSharedSecret
}
```

Comment: Your csv will likely have column headers. Those headers correspond to properties in `$line`. For example if you have a `ClientName` header, then you would use `$line.ClientName`.

Comment: take a look at what is in `$Csv` after you import the file. [*grin*] then take a look at what is in `$Line` while in the `foreach`. you need to address those properties with something like `$Line.Name`.

Comment: Ok. So I went ahead and added the $Line.ClientName, but getting the following error.

Comment: New-NpsRadiusClient : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:31
+     New-NpsRadiusClient -Name $Line.ClientName -Address $Line.IPAddre ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-NpsRadiusClient], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Nps.Commands.NewNpsRadiusClientCommand.   Not sure what am I doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: `-Name $Line.ClientName` --> `-Name $Line.Name`. You should use the EXACT field names as in the csv file.